# why is it that WooCommerce REST API returns total orders 0 for a customer but has 1 order for that customer in order table?

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on WooCommerce REST API. I am fetching customers and orders. I want to know how WooCommerce calcluates total number of orders as for some customers it is returning less results than the record found in orders table. Is there any issue with API?
here is the customer table result: [Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYg0N.png)
here is the order table
[Orders Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynTve.png). Sorry stack overflow only allows me to add links of the images. 
BTW you can clearly see that customer has one order but in customer table, it shows 0 orders, this data is returned by woocommerce rest api, so there is no chance of error from me. I can't add full image of DB due to some privacy issue and company rules.

Comment: can paste in your code? you can x-out sensitive info (key, url, etc)